# Special characters not showing when exporting HTML table to XLS

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, character-encoding, html-table

I have an HTML table generated from a query to a WordPress database. Everything is working fine with the table, all the values are showing as expected, but when I export the table to an XLS file, everything works fine except for the special characters.
The site is in spanish, so it uses a lot of special characters like Ñ Ó Á

This is the plugin that I'm using [table2excel](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html)

Every help or hint would be appreciated.

---

Extra information: There's a possible solution that is not working for me, it says that i need to add this line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="\"text/html;" charset="utf-8\"">` right after the `<head>` tag of the .js file of the plugin but when i add the line, the plugin didn't work at all.

Comment: What happens to the characters in Excel? Are they omitted? Do they show up as squares, or just `n`, `o`, `a`?

Comment: It should look like this: Teléfono and it shows like TelÃ©fono

Comment: When you go to save the spreadsheet as `XLS`, try instead: Save As -> "Text (Tab Delimited)" then open in Notepad and Save As, and set encoding to UTF-8 (default is ANSI). Does that keep the original Spanish characters, when you open back in Excel?  or try saving as CSV (Comma Delimited)

Comment: The problem is that there's a button that generates the XLS and the user should open the file to review some sensitive data. I can't ask the user to follow this steps. I found a possible solution, but it's not working for me. The question has been updated with that possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer myself, and the only problem with the  tag that i added is the formatting, instead of

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="\"text/html;" charset="utf-8\"">
```

It should be:

```
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">
```

Now it's working without problems.
Thanks!